# WkHtmlToPdf Unreadable Fonts

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I installed `wkhtmltopdf` in a `VPS/Centos` .
But it seems that it cannot find the fonts (I have all `type1` and  `fonts-75dpi` installed).
In php, this is the result of

```
exec(wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com test.pdf);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution for Cento6

```
yum install libXext  libXrender  fontconfig  libfontconfig.so.1
yum install urw-fonts
```

Answer (score 1):

For if anyone interested, I solved my problems by installing true type fonts. After that wkhtmltopdf was able to display these fonts.

Ubuntu (18.04)

```
apt install fonts-droid-fallback ttf-dejavu fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```

Alpine Linux (3.9)

```
apk add ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family
```